# How to handle a very generic function as argument in a performant way?

Tags: c++, performance, function

Assume we want to raster a huge number of lines as fast as possible and we want the actual plotting function be as abstract as possible, that is of all the pixel plotting functions we need, the only thing they have in common is that their input is the pixel coordinate:

```
void plot(int x, int y);
```

The parameters used by the pixel plot function are set before we draw the huge amount of lines and are rarely or never changed.

**First implementation idea**

Our line drawing function could look like

```
void raster_line(void (*plot)(int, int), int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
```

The implementation of that function simply calls plot(x, y) whenever it wants to plot a pixel at (x, y). Most of the times we want to raster to a specific buffer so we define a global variable and let a plot function act on that buffer:

```
static int* buffer;
void plot(int x, int y) {
    buffer[x + y * width] = 1;
}
```

So before calling raster_line we have to set the buffer variable then we pass the plot function pointer.

**Second implementation idea**

Our line drawing function could look like

```
void raster_line(const AbstractPlot& ap, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
```

where AbstractPlot is the interface

```
class AbstractPlot {
public:
    virtual ~AbstractPlot() {}
    virtual void plot(int x, int y) const = 0;
};
```

To have the same functionality as in the first example we provide the derived class

```
class Plot : public AbstractPlot {
public:
    int* buffer;
    void plot(int x, int y) const {
        buffer[x + y * width] = 1;
    }
};
```

So before calling raster_line we create a Plot object and we initialise the buffer member then we pass the instance.

**Summary**

My testing says the first idea is ~20% faster than the second (virtual function table lookup is slow?) but I dislike the fact that I have to use global variables. I am not interested in how to draw a line but how to make the pixel plotting as generic (and fast) as possible. Are there better ways to deal with that problem?

Comment: What's "faster" depends on the compiler, on the hardware, and a myriad other factors. The only way to know, is to run your own benchmarks, and by your existing experience with the same compiler, hardware, and the same myriad other factors.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid unnecessary virtual call overhead using *static* polymorphism, in which polymorphic behaviour is resolved at compile time using templates. This is the approach taken by most of the C++ standard library, *e.g.,* `std::sort`. Hence

```
template <class F>
void raster_line(F plot, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
```

If `plot` is a lambda function with no captures, and hence guaranteed to be inlinable when `raster_line` is instantiated, then there is no overhead at all when optimization is turned on. If the plot function needs to have some state, you can wrap it in a functor class or a lambda with captures, without imposing any overhead upon the calls which do not need to access any state.

The main disadvantage of this approach is that `raster_line`'s definition will have to be placed in the header, and compiled by every translation unit that includes the header. It sounds like runtime performance is really important for you in this particular case, so accepting a small increase in compilation time is probably a worthwhile tradeoff. But you should be careful about doing it *everywhere* because then the increase in compilation time can be considerable and the improvement in runtime slight.